# Junit testing for annotated controller

Tags: spring-mvc, junit

How could I test following method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "users/registration";
        }

        // create user
        service.create(user);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

How could I test the @Valid and the BindingResult?

```
public void testRegister() {
        try {
        request.setMethod("POST");
        request.setRequestURI("/users");
            request.setParameter("email", "bla@gmail.com");
        request.setParameter("prename", "Cyril");
        request.setParameter("surname", "bla");
        request.setParameter("password", "123");
        request.setParameter("repeat", "123");
        request.setParameter("birthdate", "2000-01-01");
        request.setParameter("city", "Baden");


            ModelAndView mAv = adapter.handle(request, response, usersController);

            assertEquals("redirect:/", mAv.getViewName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail();
        }
    }
```

thx a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `@Valid` annotation, that's outside the scope of your unit test. You can trust that the Spring Framework will perform the validation for you, setting the `BindingResult` appropriately.

So really, you just need to cover your `if` check of `result.hasErrors()` - and for that, you should be mocking the `BindingResult`; here's how to do it with [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/):

```
...
@Mock
private BindingResult mockBindingResult

@Before
public void setupTest() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // While the default boolean return value for a mock is 'false',
    // it's good to be explicit anyway:  
    Mockito.when(mockBindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(false);
}

@Test
public void shouldStayOnRegistrationPageIfBindingErrors() {
    // Simulate having errors just for this test:
    Mockito.when(mockBindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);

    ModelAndView mav = controller.register(user, mockBindingResult);

    // Check that we returned back to the original form:
    assertEquals("users/registration", mav.getViewName());
}
```

I also find it's really good to use [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) (and especially the [eCobertura](http://ecobertura.johoop.de/) Eclipse plugin) to visually confirm that every line and branch is covered by unit tests.

Comment: well, but if I need to test @Valid annotation? There's a way?